# "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" with oEmbed?

Tags: javascript, cors, soundcloud

As of today, when I try to embed a sound with SoundCloud oEmbed I get the following Javascript error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked
```

Is this something I can fix on my server side or is this an issue which came up on SoundCloud's side?

Comment: the same started happening with my site.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one. At least we know SoundCloud is at fault rather than us :)
Email them at support@soundcloud.com and api@soundcloud.com to raise awareness about the issue so they can fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: I've already posted to @SoundCloudDev account on Twitter. Still waiting for an answer. https://twitter.com/andre_s_p/status/514189875898503168

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. SoundCloud must have accidentally updated their oEmbed URL. Their oembed API URL is now http://soundcloud.com/oembed instead of http://soundcloud.com/oembed.json. The SoundCloud Javascript SDK still uses soundcloud.com/oembed.json (now a 404 page) for its oEmbed function.

It's probably a mistake that was made while updating their server configuration/security and we can only hope they fix this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it was a bad routing change. Apologies for the interruption! Fix is now live.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be solved by now (23th September 2014, 3pm CET).